# SlidingTabLayout covering the first View

Tags: android

My SlidingTabLayout is covering the first view of the Fragment

Images:

what i want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4pcd.png

what i get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD4dP.png

HelpActivity:

```
<MyTab.Tools.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

my FragmentXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/help1_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/help1_tela"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the Tab and Pager are started in the general way, not modifications, just copy and paste from google SlidingTabLayout class and initialize the pager, just this =(

Comment: Your fragment looks overcomplicated. Remove the outer `RelativeLayout` and `ScrollView`.

Comment: By the way `fill_parent` is deprecated, replace them with `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<MyTab.Tools.SlidingTabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" //remove this line
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
```